# Extract first URL Segment from full URL

Tags: php, regex, slug

How can the first URL segment be extracted from the full URL? The first URL segment should be cleaned to replace the `-` with a space .

**Full URL**

```
http://www.domain.com/River-Island/River-Island-T-Shirt-with-Triangle-Girl-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2516020
```

**Desired Outpput**

```
River Island
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: I've tried `str_replace()` to replace the `-` with a space. Unfortunately I cant figure out the regex part to extract the first URL segment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use:

```
$url = 'http://www.domain.com/River-Island/River-Island-T-Shirt-with-Triangle-Girl-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2516020';
$parsed = parse_url($url);
$path = $parsed['path'];
$path_parts = explode('/', $path);
$desired_output = $path_parts[1]; // 1, because the string begins with slash (/)
```

Comment: +1 for using `parse_url`, though I'd use `parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH)`.

Comment: I used `$desired_output = $path_parts[1];` and it works perfectly.

Comment: you can also do //explode("/",trim($path, "/")); to remove noise, and use reset to get the first element //$output=reset($path_parts);

Answer (score 2):

```
$page = explode('/', substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1), 2);
echo str_replace("-"," ", $page[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `/http:\/\/[^\/]+\/([^\/]+)/i`

See here: http://regex101.com/r/lB9jN7

Comment: Slightly modified this to exclude the first segment and get everything else in nginx conf like this `^\/[^\/]+\/(.*)`. This helps to build seo-friendly urls with independent sub-directory controllers. Thumbs up!

Answer (score 0):

```
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$first = substr($path, 0, strpos($path, '/'));
```

Check the docs for these three functions. Maybe you'll have to strip a slash from the beginning of the path, I'm not sure.

Answer (score -2):

have you using CodeIgniter ...???then it could be

```
$this->uri->segment(segment number of url);
```

and its need to load uri library in Controller